# Show there is a one-to-one holomorphic map $h:\Omega\to\mathbb{D}$ satisfying $h(0)=0$, and $h'(0)>1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be the interior of the square with vertices at the points $\pm 1, \pm i$. Show there is a one-to-one holomorphic map $h:\Omega\to\mathbb{D}$ satisfying $h(0)=0$, and $h'(0)>1$.

As $\Omega$ is a non-empty open simply connected space that is not all of $\mathbb{C}$ and $0\in\Omega$, then there exists a unique conformal map $F:\Omega\to\mathbb {D}$ such that $F(0)=0$ and $F'(0)>0$ by the RMT.

Can I adjust this result to insure the first derivative is greater than $1$ at $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h:\Omega \to \Bbb D$ be the (unique) conformal mapping from $\Omega$ to the unit disk with $h(0) = 0$ and $h'(0) > 0$.

Consider the inverse mapping $g = h^{-1}$: We have $g(\Bbb D) = \Omega \subsetneq \Bbb D$ and $g(0) = 0$. The Schwarz lemma gives $|g'(0)| < 1$, so that
$$
 |h'(0)| = \frac{1}{| g'(0)|} > 1 \, .
$$

Comment: There is  a mix up of notations. I thing Schwarz Lemma is applied to $g$ so we get $|g'(0)| <1$. But the proof is valid with this change in notations. $+1$ for the answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: You are right, thanks.

Comment: How do we know that $g(\mathbb{D})\subset \mathbb{D}$? @MartinR?

Comment: @Sham: If $h$ maps $\Omega$ onto $\Bbb D$ then the inverse function $g$ maps $\Bbb D$ onto $\Omega$, and that is a (strict) subset of $\Bbb D$.

Comment: @MartinR I guess I am missing something. So $h(\Omega)=\mathbb{D}$ and $g(\mathbb{D})=\Omega$ by surjectivity. As sets, $\mathbb{D}\subsetneq\Omega $

Comment: @Sham: $\Omega$ is the square with vertices at $1, i, -1, -i$, and that is a strict *subset* of the unit disk. Or did you mean the square with vertices $\pm 1 \pm i = 1+i, -1-i, -1-i, 1-i$? That would be a superset of $\Bbb D$, but then $h'(0) < 1$.

Comment: I was thinking the latter. But the problem I am solving requires what you first said. My mistake!